# Can an enumeration be a class? - C++ [enum class] [Theory]

Tags: c++11, data-structures, enums, enumeration

### **My End Goal:**

Create the implementation of a hash-table from scratch. The twist, if the number of entries in a hash bucket is greater than 10 it is stored in Binary Search Tree, or else it is stored in a Linked List.

In my knowledge the only way to be able to achieve this is through a

```
enum class type_name { a, b };
```

**My Question:**  Can 'a', and  'b' be classes?

### **Thought Process:**

So to implement a hash table, I am thinking to make an array of the enumerated class this way, as soon the *Linked List* at any index of the array it will be replaced with a *Binary Search Tree*.

If this is not possible, what would be the best way to achieve this? My implementation for Linked List and Binary Search Tree are complete and work perfectly.

**Note:** I am not looking for a complete implemenation/ full code. I would like to be able to code it myself but I think my theory is flawed.

### **Visualization of My Idea**

```
----------------------------------H A S H  T A B L E---------------------------------------
enum class Hash { LinkedList, Tree };
INDEXES:                 0            1          2           3           4
Hash eg = new Hash [ LinkedList, LinkedList, LinkedList, LinkedList, LinkedList ]
//11th element is inserted into eg[2]
//Method to Replace Linked List with Binary Search Tree

if (eg[1].getSize() > 10) {
    Tree toReplace();
    Node *follow = eg[1].headptr; //Each linked list is made of connected
    //headptr is a pointer to the first element of the linked list
    while ( follow != nullptr ){
        toReplace.insert(follow->value);
        follow = follow.next() //Next is the pointer to the next element in the linked list
    }
}

//Now, the Linked List at eg[2] is replaced with a Binary Search Tree
Hash eg = new Hash [ LinkedList, LinkedList, Tree, LinkedList, LinkedList ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.

> An enumeration is a distinct type whose value is restricted to a range
>   of values (see below for details), which may include several
>   explicitly named constants ("enumerators"). The values of the
>   constants are values of an integral type known as the underlying type
>   of the enumeration.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

Classes will not be 'values of an integral type'.

You may be able to achieve what you want with a `tuple`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple